# rails 3 - path error when using form_for on a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes

In my rails project I'm getting the following error when I view `/subscription/new`:

```
NoMethodError in Subscriptions#new

Showing /redacted/app/views/subscriptions/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `subscriptions_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd02c8bbb28>:0x007fd0308f7a48>

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <div class="grid_6">
2:   <h1>New Subscription</h1>
3:   <p>
4:     <%= form_for @subscription, :html => { class: 'form_dark' } do |f| %>
5:       <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
6:         <div class="error_messages">
7:           <h1><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h1>
```

My routes file contains `resource :subscription` for this.

Additional code information:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_one :subscription
end
```

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :stripe_token, :user_id, :last_charge, :stripe_card_token
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :plan
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
end
```

My SubscriptionsController new method:

```
def new
    @subscription = User.find(current_user.id).build_subscription 
end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean SessionsController or SubscriptionsController?

Comment: @cdesrosiers Hey, sorry, I did mean SubscriptionsController - must have had sessions on the mind. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that when you pass form_for an object like @subscription (which has class Subscription), it expects the url subscriptions_path by default. But since you have declared subscription as a singlular resource, the url subscription_path is defined instead. You should explicitly specify this route

```
<%= form_for @subscription, url: subscription_path, :html => { class: 'form_dark' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: I believe this can also happen when you have nested resources's in your routes file. The inner resource is defined as singular (rails6)

Answer (score 0):

Two politically suspicious spots,

<del>1. You have no Subscription controller in your app</del>
 2. Have you defined `subscriptions_path` custom route in your app's route file?

after reading the your comment and correction, we are left with only the route issue

Comment: Sorry, ignore the SessionsController bit (has been fixed), I meant to type SubscriptionsController.